# Assembly Language - Directives & Instructions; Moving bytes around

Tags: assembly, x86, directive

I'm working on an Assembly Language homework assignment and do not understand how to proceed for these questions. For the first one, I understand at some point I will need to give a directive of Align 2 to force myBytes into an even numbered address, but am unsure how to specifically write that instruction. For the others, I am unsure of how to move certain bytes of an identifier without moving all of them. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
.data
myBytes BYTE 10h,20h,30h,40h
myWords WORD 3 DUP(?),2000h
myString BYTE "ABCDE"
```

> 1. Write a directive in the given data that aligns myBytes to an even-numbered address.
> 2. Write a single instruction that moves the first two bytes in myBytes to the DX register. The resulting value will be 2010h.
> 3. Write an instruction that moves the second byte in myWords to the AL register.
> 4. Write an instruction that moves all four bytes in myBytes to the EAX register.

Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
1. ALIGN myBytes 2 ???   
2. mov dx, ?????   
3. mov al, [myWords+1]   
4. mov eax, [myBytes]
```

Comment: It's best to just ask your teacher if you have no idea where to start, that's not what stackoverflow is for.

Comment: Well I've got a vague idea but I don't really know if I'm on the right track.


1. ALIGN myBytes 2
??? 2. mov dx, ?????
3. mov al, [myWords+1]
4. mov eax, [myBytes]

Comment: You haven't specified which assembler you're using.

Answer (score 0):

> Well I've got a vague idea but I don't really know if I'm on the right track.

Yep you're on the right track.

```
1. ALIGN myBytes 2 ???    <<-- correct   
2. mov dx, ?????         <-- what's difficult, you've got the rest correct.  
3. mov al, [myWords+1]   <-- correct
4. mov eax, [myBytes]    <-- correct
```

In order to unravel number 2, remember that the x86 is a little endian processor, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness